# How can I enable onmifunc completion automatically?

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion

I want to enable omnifunc in my MacVim whenever I start to type in a few of leading words, such that whenever I type `np.`, the completion list pops up to show me the candidates (e.g. `np.random`, `np.trunc`, etc...).

In default, you are bothered to type in `<c-x><c-o>` to make the list pop up. [In the post over Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160744/show-vim-omnicomplete-on-certain-characters-instead-of-ctrl-x-ctrl-o), some users assign the combination to different keymaps (e.g. just type in `:` to make the list shown up).

However, I want to call the list without typing in any keys, much like you can do in Xcode. I also want to get out of the suggestion if I don't need it, much like in Xcode, which I think is not feasible in standard settings.

How can I make it in Vim?

I use Vim 7.4 and neocomplete.